# Difference between path.normalize and path.resolve in Node.js

Tags: node.js, path

What is the difference (if any) between `path.normalize(your_path)` and `path.resolve(your_path)`?

I know `path.resolve(...)` can accept multiple arguments, but is the behavior with a single argument the same as calling `path.normalize()`?

**EDIT:** If they are supposed to behave the same way, I don't understand the purpose of exposing the `path.normalize(...)` function when you can simply pass the path into `path.resolve(...)` Or, maybe, it's for documentation purposes.  For example, they say in the documentation for `path.resolve(...)`:

> ... The resulting path is normalized, and ...

Exposing the `path.normalize(...)` makes it easier to explain what "normalized" means?  I don't know.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

`path.normalize` gets rid of the extra `.`, `..`, etc. in the path. `path.resolve` resolves a path into an absolute path. Example (my current working directory was `/Users/mtilley/src/testing`):

```
> path.normalize('../../src/../src/node')
'../../src/node'
> path.resolve('../../src/../src/node')
'/Users/mtilley/src/node'
```

In other words, `path.normalize` is "What is the shortest path I can take that will take me to the same place as the input", while `path.resolve` is "What is my destination if I take this path."

Note however that `path.normalize()` is **much** more context-independent than `path.resolve()`. Had `path.normalize()` been context-*de*pendent (i.e. if it had taken into consideration the current working directory), the result in the example above would've been `../node`, because that's the shortest path one could take from `/Users/mtilley/src/testing` to `/Users/mtilley/src/node`.

Ironically, this means that `path.resolve()` produces a relative path in absolute terms (you could execute it anywhere, and it would produce the same result), whereas `path.normalize()` produces an absolute path in relative terms (you must execute it in the path relative to which you want to calculate the absolute result).

Comment: Also note that path.normalize can handle any paths you might want to normalize and means only string manipulation of the path, while path.resolve will use the filesystem and current directory to resolve the path to an absolute path. This makes them behave quite different as path.normalize might be used on a path inside a tar file, on a remote filesystem, or something entirely abstract.

Comment: How are they different from path.join?

Comment: What confused me about the doc is that `path.normalize()` does NOT remove `../` from the beginning of the path.  It does not combine it with the cwd if it's a relative path.  I can't think of any time I would ever want to use just `path.normalize()` instead of `path.resolve()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Another way to think of resolve is as a sequence of cd commands in a shell.

Links to [path.resolve](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_path) and [path.normalize](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path) in the documentation. I mostly don't want to just provide links in an answer but the Node.js docs are very decent.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the purpose of exposing the normalize(...) function when you can simply pass the path into path.resolve(...)

Comment: The path you are normalizing might not actually exist in the filesystem, e.g. you might be normalizing a path to a file that you're going to create, or you might be normalizing relative URL paths.

Comment: Actually I don't know why you would use normalize over resolve either.

Comment: normalize does not complete the path to an absolute path. So it can be used to get a sane path for some ressources relative to another ressource, which can be used inside HTML to reference a file chosen by the user for example. As the normalized path is always simple (no extra `../`) it can be easily checked to ensure the user only choses files from certain locations and has no chance viewing private files outside this locations.

Comment: @BMiner Actually, path.normalize() is very useful for passing back an image SRC path, in an Electron app. You cannot pass back an absolute system path to the ipcRenderer, for such purposes. The SRC attribute can only be an absolute URL, data, base or relative path.